# Finding all positions of substring in a larger string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string

I have a large string I need to parse, and I need to find all the instances of `extract"(me,i-have lots. of]punctuation`, and store the index of each to a list.

So say this piece of string was in the beginning and middle of the larger string, both of them would be found, and their indexes would be added to the `List`. and the `List` would contain `0` and the other index whatever it would be.

I've been playing around, and the `string.IndexOf` does *almost* what I'm looking for, and I've written some code - but it's not working and I've been unable to figure out exactly what is wrong:

```
List<int> inst = new List<int>();
int index = 0;
while (index < source.LastIndexOf("extract\"(me,i-have lots. of]punctuation", 0) + 39)
{
    int src = source.IndexOf("extract\"(me,i-have lots. of]punctuation", index);
    inst.Add(src);
    index = src + 40;
}
```

- `inst` = The list
- `source` = The large string

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Here's an example extension method for it:

```
public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for (int index = 0;; index += value.Length) {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
        if (index == -1)
            return indexes;
        indexes.Add(index);
    }
}
```

If you put this into a static class and import the namespace with `using`, it appears as a method on any string, and you can just do:

```
List<int> indexes = "fooStringfooBar".AllIndexesOf("foo");
```

For more information on extension methods, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Also the same using an iterator:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
    for (int index = 0;; index += value.Length) {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
        if (index == -1)
            break;
        yield return index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use IEnumerable<int> and yield return index instead of the indexes list?

Comment: @m0sa: Good point. Added another version just for the fun of it.

Comment: Does the use of yield have any incidence in the performance? Does the retrieval of the objects becomes async or lazy? Os is it just syntactic sugar and both codes are the same?

Comment: @PedroC88: Using `yield` will make the code "lazy". It won't collect all the indexes into an in-memory list within the method. What kind of practical effect that has on performance depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for (int index = 0;; index += value.Length) {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
        if (index == -1)
            return indexes;
        indexes.Add(index);
        index--;
    }
}

This covers tests cases like AOOAOOA
Output 0 and 3

Comment: I'm confused by the exception text provided. You're telling the user that the string may not be empty if the string is null or empty?

Comment: @Paul: "May not" as in "must not". If you don't like the wording you can always suggest an edit, but I don't think it's that hard to understand.

Comment: Aha. Completely missed the meaning of the message. Thank you.

Comment: Attention! Due to adding `value.Length` you may miss nested matches! Example: "This is a NestedNestedNested match test!" with matching for "NestedNested" will find only one index, but not the nested one. To fix this just add `+=1` in loop instead of `+=value.Length`.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I like this answer. I would change one thing. Instead of throwing an exception, just return null or empty list as this would show that nothing was found without run time exceptions being thrown.

Comment: Your solution is not correct! for finding "aa" in "aaa", the output should be [0, 1] but your algorithm returns [0]

Comment: @M.Khooryani Depends on the definition of correct. This finds non-overlapping substrings, which seemed to be what OP was looking for.

Comment: You should throw an exception

Comment: Warning: IndexOutOfRangeException when string contains German "ß" character. Example: "Vertrag abschließen", search "abschliessen". To fix it, go with the suggestion from @ChristophMeißner to replace `+=value.Length` with `+=1`

Answer (score 25):

Why don't you use the built in RegEx class:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAllIndexes(this string source, string matchString)
{
   matchString = Regex.Escape(matchString);
   foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(source, matchString))
   {
      yield return match.Index;
   }
}
```

If you do need to reuse the expression then compile it and cache it somewhere.  Change the matchString param to a Regex matchExpression in another overload for the reuse case.

Comment: This doesn't compile

Comment: what is `indexes`? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: My bad it's a remnant.  Delete that line.

Comment: Beware that this method has the same flaw as the accepted answer. If your source string is "ccc" and pattern is "cc" then it will return only one occurrence.

Comment: @user280498 This is not necessarily a "flaw" depending on the usage scenario...

Answer (score 19):

using LINQ

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IndexOfAll(this string sourceString, string subString)
{
    return Regex.Matches(sourceString, subString).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Index);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the subString though.

Comment: This is preferable to the accepted solution because of its lower cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: seems not working, for "aaa" and "aa"  inputs.

Comment: that is the expected behavior... when you match "aa" in "aaa"  what remains is "xxa" that does not match "aa"

Comment: Aha, the next comment does this -- It just so happens my file names begin with AA. :)

I'm getting a string back, which will be parsed to make the body text of an email.

There are reasons I can't modify the code that returns the message.  I have parse the returned message.

Example names are AA.AAOAKSINF02A.DEV.DAT.  There is a certain count.  I have to find all file names and verify the correct count exists, then account for any that didn't happen.

OK, how to do this?

I need to find each AA. and its next .DEV instance.  Between these are the file names and dates.

Answer (score 10):

Polished version + case ignoring support:

```
public static int[] AllIndexesOf(string str, string substr, bool ignoreCase = false)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ||
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(substr))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("String or substring is not specified.");
    }

    var indexes = new List<int>();
    int index = 0;

    while ((index = str.IndexOf(substr, index, ignoreCase ? StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase : StringComparison.Ordinal)) != -1)
    {
        indexes.Add(index++);
    }

    return indexes.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It could be done in efficient time complexity using [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm in O(N + M) where N is the length of `text` and M is the length of the `pattern`.

This is the implementation and usage:

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndicesOf(this string text, string pattern)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
        }
        return Kmp(text, pattern);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> Kmp(string text, string pattern)
    {
        int M = pattern.Length;
        int N = text.Length;

        int[] lps = LongestPrefixSuffix(pattern);
        int i = 0, j = 0; 

        while (i < N)
        {
            if (pattern[j] == text[i])
            {
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            if (j == M)
            {
                yield return i - j;
                j = lps[j - 1];
            }

            else if (i < N && pattern[j] != text[i])
            {
                if (j != 0)
                {
                    j = lps[j - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] LongestPrefixSuffix(string pattern)
    {
        int[] lps = new int[pattern.Length];
        int length = 0;
        int i = 1;

        while (i < pattern.Length)
        {
            if (pattern[i] == pattern[length])
            {
                length++;
                lps[i] = length;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (length != 0)
                {
                    length = lps[length - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    lps[i] = length;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return lps;
    }
```

and this is an example of how to use it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "this is a test";
        string pattern = "is";
        foreach (var index in text.AllIndicesOf(pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index); // 2 5
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the performance of this compared to the optimal IndexOf implementation, where the search start index is set to the end of the previous match on each iteration?

Comment: Comparing IndexOf with AllIndicesOf is incorrect since their output is different. Using the IndexOf method in each iteration, enormously increases the time complexity to O(N^2 M), while optimal complexity is O(N+M). KMP doesn't work similarly to the naive approach, it uses a precomputed array(LPS) to avoid searching from the start. Recommend you read the KMP algorithm. The last paragraphs of the "Background" section in Wikipedia explain how it works in O(N).

Comment: Other  string-searching algorithms in C# ?

Comment: I do not understand why more people have not accepted this answer. It performs better on long input strings and with long search strings. It is more complex to read, but taking it as a black box and using it as the go-to for solving this problem with long input strings is the way to go.

Comment: @drdwilcox because this answer was posted 10 years after the verified answer.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that at least two proposed solutions don't handle overlapping search hits.  I didn't check the one marked with the green checkmark. Here is one that handles overlapping search hits:

```
    public static List<int> GetPositions(this string source, string searchString)
    {
        List<int> ret = new List<int>();
        int len = searchString.Length;
        int start = -1;
        while (true)
        {
            start = source.IndexOf(searchString, start +1);
            if (start == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                ret.Add(start);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<int> GetPositions(string source, string searchString)
{
    List<int> ret = new List<int>();
    int len = searchString.Length;
    int start = -len;
    while (true)
    {
        start = source.IndexOf(searchString, start + len);
        if (start == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ret.Add(start);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
List<int> list = GetPositions("bob is a chowder head bob bob sldfjl", "bob");
// list will contain 0, 22, 26
```

Comment: add this check and you're good to go:                 
 if (searchString == null || searchString == String.Empty ) { ret.Add(-1); return ret; };

Answer (score 2):

Without Regex, using string comparison type:

```
string search = "123aa456AA789bb9991AACAA";
string pattern = "AA";
Enumerable.Range(0, search.Length)
   .Select(index => { return new { Index = index, Length = (index + pattern.Length) > search.Length ? search.Length - index : pattern.Length }; })
   .Where(searchbit => searchbit.Length == pattern.Length && pattern.Equals(search.Substring(searchbit.Index, searchbit.Length),StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   .Select(searchbit => searchbit.Index)
```

This returns {3,8,19,22}. Empty pattern would match all positions.

For multiple patterns:

```
string search = "123aa456AA789bb9991AACAA";
string[] patterns = new string[] { "aa", "99" };
patterns.SelectMany(pattern => Enumerable.Range(0, search.Length)
   .Select(index => { return new { Index = index, Length = (index + pattern.Length) > search.Length ? search.Length - index : pattern.Length }; })
   .Where(searchbit => searchbit.Length == pattern.Length && pattern.Equals(search.Substring(searchbit.Index, searchbit.Length), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   .Select(searchbit => searchbit.Index))
```

This returns {3, 8, 19, 22, 15, 16}

Comment: LOL, see my comment above.  I went through all that work only to read just a few more lines down to see "Without Regex, using string comparison type:"  Thank you so much for this.  It's too easy to ignore the answer with only 1 upvote.  Glad I saw this.

Comment: var x = Enumerable.Range(0, search.Length - pattern.Length + 1).Where(index => pattern.Equals(search.Substring(index, pattern.Length))); is a shorter version of your first answer.

Answer (score 1):

[@csam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642073/641833) is correct in theory, although his code will not complie and can be refractored to

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IndexOfAll(this string sourceString, string matchString)
{
    matchString = Regex.Escape(matchString);
    return from Match match in Regex.Matches(sourceString, matchString) select match.Index;
}
```

Comment: if his code was incorrect you could've edited his post to correct it

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. I have to admit to being reluctant to do that, just in case I am wrong, although I don't think I am.

Comment: that's not good idea to use regex for large string. The approach takes a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Hi nice answer by @Matti Virkkunen

```
public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for (int index = 0;; index += value.Length) {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
        if (index == -1)
            return indexes;
        indexes.Add(index);
        index--;
    }
}
```

But this covers tests cases like AOOAOOA
where substring

are AOOA and AOOA

Output 0 and 3

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>> GetWordsPositions(this string input, string[] Susbtrings)
{
    Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>> WordsPositions = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>();
    IEnumerable<int> IndexOfAll = null;
    foreach (string st in Susbtrings)
    {
        IndexOfAll = Regex.Matches(input, st).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Index);
        WordsPositions.Add(st, IndexOfAll);

    }
    return WordsPositions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I figured, I'd convert the List answers to an Array of integers answer (didn't see this posted here).

```
    int[] GetPositionsAsArray(string sourceString, string searchString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceString))
        {
            return new int[] { -1 };
        }
        else
        {    
            int[] ret = new int[sourceString.Length];
            int len = searchString.Length;               
            int index = 0;
            int start = -len;
            while (true)
            {
                start = sourceString.IndexOf(searchString, start + len);
                if (start == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ret[index] = start;
                    index++;
                }
            }
            Array.Resize(ref ret, index); //optional
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code I've used for finding multiple instances of a string within a larger string, your code would look like:

```
List<int> inst = new List<int>();
int index = 0;
while (index >=0)
{
    index = source.IndexOf("extract\"(me,i-have lots. of]punctuation", index);
    inst.Add(index);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: There are two problems here: First, you always add -1 to your result list, which is not a valid result. Second, the code does not terminate due to `indexOf` returning -1 and the `index++`. I would use a  `while (true)` with a `break;` if the result of `IndexOf` is -1.

Answer (score -1):

I found this [example](https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2013/10/c-example-string-find-all-occurrences.html) and incorporated it into a function:

```
    public static int solution1(int A, int B)
    {
        // Check if A and B are in [0...999,999,999]
        if ( (A >= 0 && A <= 999999999) && (B >= 0 && B <= 999999999))
        {
            if (A == 0 && B == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            // Make sure A < B
            if (A < B)
            {                    
                // Convert A and B to strings
                string a = A.ToString();
                string b = B.ToString();
                int index = 0;

                // See if A is a substring of B
                if (b.Contains(a))
                {
                    // Find index where A is
                    if (b.IndexOf(a) != -1)
                    {                            
                        while ((index = b.IndexOf(a, index)) != -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(A + " found at position " + index);
                            index++;
                        }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        return b.IndexOf(a);
                    }
                    else
                        return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(A + " is not in " + B + ".");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(A + " must be less than " + B + ".");
               // Console.ReadLine();

                return -1;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A or B is out of range.");
            //Console.ReadLine();

            return -1;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int A = 53, B = 1953786;
        int C = 78, D = 195378678;
        int E = 57, F = 153786;

        solution1(A, B);
        solution1(C, D);
        solution1(E, F);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Returns:

53 found at position 2

78 found at position 4
78 found at position 7

57 is not in 153786

Comment: Hi Mark, I see that you're new to stackoverflow. This answer doesn't add anything to this old question, there are already much better answers. If answering a question like this in the future, please try to explain why your answer contains some information or value which does not already exist in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

How is this alternative implementation?

```
 public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int HowMany(this string str, char needle)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int nextIndex = 0;
            for (; nextIndex != -1; )
            {
                nextIndex = str.IndexOf(needle, nextIndex);
                if (nextIndex != -1)
                {
                    counter++;
                    //step over to the next char
                    nextIndex++;
                }
            }
            return counter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't aks questions in answers. *Explain* instead. In this case: explain why your answer improves all other answers given here.

Answer (score -1):

you can use linq to select and enumerate all elements, then find by any string:

I've created a class:

```
class Pontos 
{
    //index on string
    public int Pos { get; set; }
    //caractere 
    public string Caractere { get; set; }           
}
```

And use like this:

```
int count = 0;

var pontos = texto.Select(y => new Pontos { Pos = count++, Caractere = y.ToString() }).Where(x=>x.Caractere == ".").ToList();
```

then:
input string:
[image]

output list:
[image]

PS: `SeForNumero` is another field of my class, I need this for my own purposes, but is not necessary to this use.