# Using IndexOf inside of a function in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, lua, indexof

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out the logic in what I'm trying to accomplish. What I'm trying to do is figure out how can I make 'Event' an auto complete item, storing it--later checking to see if it exists, or is incorrectly spelled.

I'm using C#.

Here is the fluent explanation:

Function:

```
function Test(Event)
end
```

Now, what I want to do is use:

```
if(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("Event"))
{ 
    // Store item via Auto Complete Item
}
```

Once it is stored, I don't really know how to get the other part of the function. Like, how big the inside of the function will be, until it reaches an "end" point.

Let's say, here is a bigger part of a function:

```
function Test(Event)
    local k = 0
    if k == 0 then
        Event:SetValue(k)
    end
end
```

Now how would I get the 'Event', when it is inside of an 'if' statement? Do I use 'LastIndexOf'?

For short:

- Check to see if 'Event' exists.
- If 'Event' exists, store it.
- Once 'Event' is stored, we can make sure there are no errors inside of the 'function' once the last 'end' is written.

Examples or written documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure whether this may help or not but why not create an array first and everytime you run this function (Test(Event)) you add an item to the array?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but are you trying to get every instance of the word `Event`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the word Event, inside of the 'function', and stop once the last 'end' is distributed. @Picrofo: I actually tried a list, but I cannot really figure out how to stop once 'end' ends the function--because you have multiple ends, if using 'if' statements.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: @user1729639 Sorry I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: keyboardP: Thanks. I'll look into this! @Picrofo: How can you not understand it? 'function Test(Event)', I want to get everything inside of the 'function' until it reaches an 'end' to close the 'function', whilst trying to find out if 'Event' doesn't contain a user error. Examples are in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i'm not sure what the function below is intended to do, and lines 2 and 3 of the below function don't need to be there).

```
function Test(Event)
    local k = 0
    if k == 0 then
        Event:SetValue(k)
    end
end
```

But if I understand you right and your wanting to retrieve the value of 'Event', you should use `return` as such..

```
function Test(Event)
    local k = 0
    if k == 0 then
        Event:SetValue(k)
    end
    return Event;
end
```

But like I said, the function will be pretty useless as the below example illustrates:

```
local Event = "ham sandwich";
function Test(Event)
    local k = 0
    if k == 0 then
        Event = k
    end
    return Event;
end

print(Test(Event));
0
```

This is because, in your function, k is always going to be 0.

I've come back to this, long after writing it, and I've noticed that I didn't actually answer your question!.

Here is a function which will store EVENT and pass EVENT to you to use after the last 'end'.

```
local eventArray = {};
```

If we have declare 'eventArray' as a local here ( not in a function or block of code), we can be confident that it can be accessed anywhere in your code.

```
function GetEvent(event)
    eventArray = eventArray or {};
    if ( event == nil ) then
        return;
    else
        table.insert(eventArray, event);
        return event;
    end
end
```

Because the function returns a value, you can do this from outside the function:

```
local event1 = GetEvent(event);
```

'event1' will now hold the value that was returned by your function and of-course, the function will save it in a table too for later use if required.

If you'd like to store your events then make sure your table exists first at the start of your function ie:   eventArray = eventArray or {};

This protects against accidental deletion of the table.

The code says 'the table equals itself, but if it doesn't exist, it equals a table.  It is harmless if your table exists because it always accepts the first true statement (which in this case is 'eventArray' which does exist).

Ensuring that event exists is actually easy.  If it is impossible for event to have a boolean value, you can also use:  if ( not event ) then

I say that because event might exist with the value false.  If that was the case and you used    if ( not event ) then    it would regard that statement as true because the value of event is false.  This is because false and nil are not the same thing, unlike some languages.

Keep in mind that false and "false" are not the same thing either.  The first is a boolean value (either true or false) and the second is just a string of text that says "false" and is treated like any other string.

But to be safe, "if ( event == nil )" is often best.

Using return tells the function to just stop right there because there's no point in continuing.  So if event doesn't exist, the function will end prematurely.

Hugh