# Send a string sequentially from Client to Server

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to send a string sequentially over to the Server, with a list of commands. Each command is separated by a '#'. So if I for example have this string:

"Go#load"

How can I send the first command "Go", let it perform and then send the next command, until the string is over?

Obvious I can't split the string in three strings. and I don't have the server code.
Maybe I can use a foreach with a split?

Comment: Well what's the protocol? Everything depends on that - and we basically don't know anything about it at the moment. What do you mean by "obvious I can't do split the string in three string" - why not?

Comment: I mean that i cant't do this: 
string hi="Go";
string hi2="load".
Obvious i can use the string function 'split', if ever it can serve. Did you mean network protocol? If you meant it, the protocol woluld be TCP.

Comment: What do you mean by "if ever it can serve"? And there's an application protocol on top of TCP, but we still don't know what that is. How do you indicate in the protocol that you've reached the end of a command?

Comment: Sorry I solve it, there was a stupid error. I ask sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Note very clear what you are trying to acheve *exactly*, but you may do something like 
*for a single case* (just a sniplet):

```
var str = "Go#load";
var curindex = 0; 
var index = str.IndexOf("#"); 
var command = str.Substring(curIndex, index); 
curindex = index;
```

For complete function look on [Finding ALL positions of a substring in a large string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp)

Using those ones you find all occurrences of "#" symbol in the string, and all in between of them is a `command`, according to your description.

Comment: @Luaan: The question says that he has a string and willing to send it without executing split.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string like this :

```
        var input = "Go#load";
        var list = input.Split('#');
```

Now you have list of commands and by foreach loop you can call the server code

```
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            // call the server and pass the item
        }
```