# Hangman game: error if the quessword contains a letter more than once

Tags: c#, string

This is for a hangman program it works fine if the word I am guessing only contains each letter once but if it contains one or more of the letters twice when I click on the letter again nothing happens.

```
private void charGuess(char letter ) 
{
    if (!myWords[randomNum].guess_word.Contains(letter))
    {
        totalWrongGuesses(letter);
    }
    else
    {
        int tempIndex = myWords[randomNum].guess_word.IndexOf(letter);
        astericksBox.Text = astericksBox.Text
            .Remove(tempIndex,1)
            .Insert(tempIndex,letter
            .ToString());
    }

    if (!astericksBox.Text.Contains("*"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You've Won!!");  
    }
}

private int randomNumGenerator()
{
    int rndNum; // a variable to temporarily store the random number generated
    Random randomNum = new Random(); // creates a new Random object randomNum
    return rndNum = randomNum.Next(0,19); // returns a randomNum vlue between 0 and 19
}


private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    charGuess('a');
}
```

Update: I found the solution for my problem and posted it as an answer below.

Comment: So, what's your question? This is a Q&A site after all.

Comment: Your code is buggy, you remove an asterisk that was already replaced.  This is caused by having a poor data representation.  Create a Letter class, it should have an IsGuessed property.  Store them in a List.

Comment: I want to be able to select the same letter twice if nessary but if I have used the letter once pressing it again does nothing

Comment: @ Hans Passant  I remove an asterick and replace it with a letter

Comment: Look at the documentation for `IndexOf` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. It will find the **first** occurrence of a character. What do you suppose happens if you have a guessword that contains the same letter two times?

Comment: @Alex I see what you mean. Im thinking that I could change the character in guessWord to a different un used character so the next time the buttin is pressed it will find the next letter in the string

Comment: @JerryMurphy good for you, you solved it by yourself (I am not sure if it is the most perfect solution possible, but that doesn't really matter). Instead of including your solution with your question, you should post it as an answer to your question, and then accept it as "the answer". ... or you may try to further improve it, before accepting it as the answer (hint: what would happen if a user guessed `£ ?)

Comment: its not possible to guess '£' There is a button for each letter and they are the only options available but thanks for you input ill post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

replace the body of your else with

```
var indexes = AllIndexesOf(myWords[randomNum].guess_word,letter);
foreach(int i in indexes)
    astericksBox.Text = astericksBox.Text.Remove(i,1).Insert(i,letter.ToString());
```

and create this function (which i got from [Finding ALL positions of a substring in a large string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp))

```
public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value)

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for (int index = 0; ; index += value.Length)
    {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
        if (index == -1)
            return indexes;
        indexes.Add(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ XenoPuTtSss this is for a college assingnment we are only allowed use what we have cover so far and code in the function would be allowed. A comment above has given me an idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
int tempIndex = myWords[randomNum].guess_word.IndexOf(letter);
astericksBox.Text = astericksBox.Text.Remove(tempIndex,1).Insert(tempIndex,letter.ToString());
```

With this:

```
int tempIndex = 0;
do 
{
    tempIndex = myWords[randomNum].guess_word.IndexOf(letter, tempIndex);
    astericksBox.Text = astericksBox.Text.Remove(tempIndex,1).Insert(tempIndex,letter.ToString());
    tempIndex++;
}
while (tempIndex > 0);
```

And for efficiency/performance I might do this:

```
int tempIndex = 0;
var mask = astericksBox.Text.ToCharArray();
do 
{
    tempIndex = myWords[randomNum].guess_word.IndexOf(letter, tempIndex);
    mask[tempIndex] = letter;          
    tempIndex++;
}
while (tempIndex > 0);
astericksBox.Text = new string(mask);
```

That code also reads a lot easier.

Comment: This code does not work as I get an outOfRangeException. The first shorter one without the mask

Answer (score 1):

I changed the else statement in charGuess to the code below and it now works as expected.

```
else
            {
                int tempIndex = myWords[randomNum].guess_word.IndexOf(letter);
                String tempWord = myWords[randomNum].guess_word;
                astericksBox.Text = astericksBox.Text.Remove(tempIndex,1).Insert(tempIndex,letter.ToString());
                tempWord = tempWord.Remove(tempIndex, 1).Insert(tempIndex, "£");
                myWords[randomNum].guess_word = tempWord;

            }
```

Comment: Won't this make you guess the same letter repeatedly to reveal it more than once? Hangman games I've played only make you guess a letter once, and then show all occurance of it. Also, since it looks like you have a word bank, this will destroy that word in the bank if it were to come up again on a later game. You really should take a look at the answer I posted.

Comment: I never thought of that but you are right. I will think on it and have another go.

Comment: Okay. There was a bug in my answer that is fixed now.