# How to search for specific char in an array and how to then manipulate that index in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, findall

Okay, so I'm creating a hangman game and everything functions so far, including what I'm TRYING to do in the question.

But it feels like there is a much more efficient method of obtaining the char that is also easier to manipulate the index.

```
protected static void alphabetSelector(string activeWordAlphabet)
    {
        char[] activeWord = activeWordAlphabet.ToCharArray();

        string activeWordString = new string(activeWord);
        Console.WriteLine("If you'd like to guess a letter, enter the letter. \n 
        If you'd like to guess the word, please type in the word. --- testing answer{0}", 
        activeWordString);

        //Console.WriteLine("For Testing Purposes ONLY");
        String chosenLetter = Console.ReadLine();
        //Char[] letterFinder = Array.FindAll(activeWord, s => s.Equals(chosenLetter));
        //string activeWordString = new string(activeWord);

        foreach (char letter in activeWord);
        {
            if(activeWordString.Contains(chosenLetter))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", activeWordString);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("errrr...wrong!");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }



        }



    }
```

*I have broken up the code in some areas to prevent the reader from having to scroll sideways. If this is bothersome, please let me know and I'll leave it in the future.*

So this code will successfully print out the 'word' whenever I select the correct letter from the random word *(I have the console print the actual word so that I can test it successfully each time).* It will also print 'wrong' when I choose a letter NOT in the string.

But I feel like I should be able to use the 
    Array.FindAll(activeWord, ...)
functionality *or some other way*. But every time I try and reorder the arguments, it gives me all kinds of different errors and tells me to redo my arguments.

So, if you can look at this and find an easier method of searching the actual array for the user-selected 'letter', please help!! Even if it's not using the Array.FindAll method!!

**Edit**

Okay, it seems like there's some confusion with what I've done and why I've done it.

I'm ONLY printing the word inside that 'if' statement to test and make sure that the foreach{if{}} will actually work to find the char inside the string. But I ultimately need to be able to provide a placeholder for a char that is successfully found, as well as being able to 'cross out' the letter (from the alphabet list not shown here).

It's hangman - surely you guys know what I'm needing it to do. It has to keep track of which letters are left in the word, which letters have been chosen, as well as which letters are left in the entire alphabet.

I'm a 4-day old newb when it comes to programming, so please. . . I'm only doing what I know to do and when I get errors, I comment things out and write more until I find something that works.

Comment: The char array conversion is not necessary since enumerating a string in a foreach loop will implicitly do that. The `activeWordString` string is not necessary either as it's the exact same string as activeWordAlphabet. And you can use `if (activeWordAlphabet.Contains(chosenLetter[0]))` at last you could validate that there is only one character entered.

Comment: Wait, so you just want to know if a character exists in a string?

Comment: you aren't even using `letter` in your loop... Why not just do `if activeWordString.Contains(chosenLetter))` and get rid of the loop altogether?

Comment: @crush -- well, it's a little more than that. This is JUST to make sure I can FIND the letter within the array, which I have done. But I also need to be able to take that letter - change something within the array so that a 'placeholder' exists so that I can go back through the 'word' and say "okay, he has already guessed letters at index[0], [4], and [6]. Once I have completed that, I must ALSO be able to take those letters (and multiple indexes if there are the same letters multiple times in the array) and 'cross' them out in my alphabet list above the game console. I don't think this works

Comment: Are you trying to implement Hangman?

Comment: @austinwernli when I initially created the foreach loop, I tried doing that, but it was saying that I couldn't convert, or that the arguments were invalid -- I don't know that I tried it specifically in the way you just laid out, but I think I'll try that.

Comment: This code literally doesn't do anything you say it does... All it does is print the word, or errr wrong... How do you say this functions how you want it to?

Comment: @crush - implement hangman? The game I'm creating IS hangman, yes, but I'm not trying to create the actual gallow/body yet. I want to get the actual game to work properly for now.

Comment: @austinwernli - it printing the word is ONLY to test and make sure that the if statement checks that the string has the char in it -- I can add different "do this/do that" statements within the if(true) statement later. But it seems like I should be able to use the Array.FindAll without needing to do the ifs or the foreach.

Comment: Because it seems the most organized way is to have each letter in the string remain inside of a char[] so that each index can be acted upon individually w/o messing with the string itself. I can ALSO display each index separately and keep track of it separately this way. At least this is what is SEEMS like in my head when I think about it.

Comment: This may help in getting all the indexes of 1 character: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: what about List.indexof(<char>)?It returns index. And use linq instead of classical foreach.

Comment: @AvsenevSlava - this is helpful, because I haven't used a list before, but probably should take a look at it now. :) linq instead of classical foreach? Can you give me a reference to such thing things? I really have no clue about using linq, what it is or does differently than foreach. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this demo I put together for you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eP9TQM

I'd suggest creating a second string for the display string. Use a `StringBuilder`, and you can replace the characters in it at specific indices while creating the fewest number of stringobjects in the process.

```
string word = "your word or phrase here";

//Initialize a new StringBuilder that will display the word with placeholders.
StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder(word.Length); //You know the display word is the same length as the original word
display.Append('-', word.Length); //Fill it with placeholders.
```

So now you have your phrase/word, and a string builder full of characters that need to be discovered.

Go ahead and convert the display StringBuilder to a string that you can check on each pass to see if it equals your word:

```
var displayString = display.ToString();

//Loop until the display string is equal to the word
while (!displayString.Equals(word))
{
    //Inside here your logic will follow.
}
```

So you are basically looping until the person answers here. You could of course go back and add logic to limit the number of attempts, or whatever you desire as an alternate exit strategy.

Inside this logic, you will check if they guessed a letter or a word based on how many characters they entered.

If they guessed a word, the logic is simple. Check if the guessed word is the same as the hidden word. If it is, then you `break` the loop and they are done. Otherwise, guessing loops back around.

If they guessed a letter, the logic is pretty straightforward, but more involved.

First get the character they guessed, just because it may be easier to work with this way.

```
char guess = input[0];
```

Now, look over the word for instances of that character:

```
//Look for instances of the character in the word.
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; ++i)
{
    //If the current index in the word matches their guess, then update the display.
    if (char.ToUpperInvariant(word[i]) == char.ToUpperInvariant(guess))
        display[i] = word[i];
}
```

The comments above should explain the idea here.

Update your displayString at the bottom of the loop so that it will check against the hidden word again:

```
displayString = display.ToString();
```

That's really all you need to do here. No fancy Linq needed.

Comment: Holy crap - that's awesome (the dotnetfiddle demo). :) The stringbuilder seems to be perfect for what I'm looking to do. And while I don't QUITE understand all of what is there, I'll be searching the msdn for it and screwing around with it. In fact, I think I'm going to just create a new project and start it over from scratch and implement this type of structure. :) THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @Newbie StringBuilder is a buffer of chars, sort of like a String, except that Strings are immutable. Immutable means they can't be changed after they are created. Which means, if you want to change a character of a String, you have to create a new String. In your case, that would be each char. That's why it's better to have a StringBuilder that you can manipulate without creating new String objects for every small change. Once you have your String finalized, you just call .ToString() on the StringBuilder, and it will turn its char array into an immutable String for you. Hope this helps too.

Comment: AHHH. Thank you for that explanation. My God does that ever help! And see, I figured I couldn't change the 'stringVar' so I wanted to make sure it was transferred to an array and I assumed I could just switch each 'index' and replace the index with character of some type that I could 'check' later, which would let me know which '_' to fill in once the person started guessing the right letters. But wow, this is amazing stuff. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Newbie sounds like you were basically trying to do what StringBuilder does for you! So you were on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

Ok your code is really confusing, even with your edit.

First, why these 2 lines of code since activeWordAlphabet is a string :

```
char[] activeWord = activeWordAlphabet.ToCharArray();

string activeWordString = new string(activeWord);
```

Then you do your foreach.
For the word "FooBar", if the player types 'F', you will print
    FooBar
    FooBar
    FooBar
    FooBar
    FooBar
    FooBar

How does this help you in anything?

I think you have to review your algorithm. The string type have the function you need

```
int chosenLetterPosition = activeWord.IndexOf(chosenLetter, alreadyFoundPosition)
```

`alreadyFoundPosition` is an int from where the function will search the letter

`IndexOf()` returns -1 if the letter is not find or a positive number.
You can save this position with your letter in a dictionary to use it again as your new 'alreadyFoundPosition' if the chosenLetter is already in the dictionary

Comment: First, I'd like to thank you for taking time out to respond. But I'd also like to point out that I stated, very clearly, why I had the console print out the 'word' several times - it was merely a test to see if the foreach{{if}} was successful, and it was. Also

'char[] activeWord = activeWordAlphabet.ToCharArray()'

is there in order to bring the 'string' from a different method, into this method, and then turn it into an array. I then turned it back into a string because when I tried doing the foreach{{if}} statement, it said I couldn't use the array, for whatever reason.

Comment: Also, I'm VERY new to this. I haven't even looked at Indexes, how they work, how to properly call them, how to create or manipulate them. So the information derived from the answers here are quite overwhelming and I'll be sifting through a lot of new information and trying what works. My code is set up in a way that works based around the knowledge I have - I cannot write code for knowledge I don't have, but now I know there are other ways to do this, which was my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer. Because I don't have a lot of tasks today :)

```
class Letter
{
    public bool ischosen { get; set; }
    public char value { get; set; }
}

class LetterList
{
    public LetterList(string word)
    {
        _lst = new List<Letter>();
        word.ToList().ForEach(x => _lst.Add(new Letter() { value = x }));
    }

    public bool FindLetter(char letter)
    {
        var search = _lst.Where(x => x.value == letter).ToList();
        search.ForEach(x=>x.ischosen=true);
        return search.Count > 0 ? true : false;
    }

    public string NotChosen()
    {
        var res = "";
        _lst.Where(x => !x.ischosen).ToList().ForEach(x => { res += x.value; });
        return res;
    }

    List<Letter> _lst;


}
```

How to use

```
var abc = new LetterList("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
var answer = new LetterList("myanswer");
Console.WriteLine("This my question. Why? write your answer please");
char x = Console.ReadLine()[0];
if (answer.FindLetter(x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("you are right!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("fail");
}
abc.FindLetter(x);

Console.WriteLine("not chosen abc:{0} answer:{1}", abc.NotChosen(), answer.NotChosen());
```

At least we used to play this game like that when i was a child.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's amazing how many different ways one can go about doing this!! I will definitely look into all the new method calls I'm seeing. I'm feeling overwhelmed right about now, but I guess I gotta' start somewhere. :)

Comment: @Newbie There are always a million ways to tackle a problem. The main thing is understanding how to analyze the problem and come up with a plan of attack. Then its' just a matter of finding the right tools for the job.