# Get index of the first character of substring in a string in C#

Tags: c#, indexing, substring

I would like to get indexes of first letters of **xx** in

> xx INC FFFFFFFF xx DE RRRRRR

The method `IndexOf` doesnt help. 
Any clue?

Comment: Why doesn't `IndexOf` help? Have you tried overload that allows a start position to be specified? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: [Finding ALL positions of a substring in a large string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an extension method like this which uses the [overload of `String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports a start index. The `StringComparison` can be used to compare case insensitively:

```
public static IList<int> AllIndexOf(this string text, string str, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
{
    IList<int> allIndexes = new List<int>();
    int index = text.IndexOf(str, comparisonType);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        allIndexes.Add(index);
        index = text.IndexOf(str, index + str.Length, comparisonType);
    }
    return allIndexes;
}
```

Then it's easy:

```
string str = "xx INC FFFFFFFF xx DE RRRRRR";
IEnumerable<int> allIndexes = str.AllIndexOf("xx", StringComparison.InvariantCulture); // 0 and 16
```