# Search for some phrases in a text file using Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

The task:

Write a program, which counts the phrases in a text file. Any sequence of characters could be given as phrase for counting, even sequences containing separators. For instance in the text "I am a student in Sofia" the phrases "s", "stu", "a" and "I am" are found respectively 2, 1, 3 and 1 times.

I know the solution with  **string.IndexOf**  or with **LINQ** or with some type of algorithm like **Aho-Corasick**. I want to do same thing with **Regex**.

This is what I've done so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CountThePhrasesInATextFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = ReadInput("file.txt");
            input.ToLower();
            List<string> phrases = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("words.txt"))
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    phrases.Add(line.Trim());
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            foreach (string phrase in phrases)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(String.Format(".*" + phrase.ToLower() + ".*"));
                int mathes = regex.Matches(input).Count;
                Console.WriteLine(phrase + " ----> " + mathes);
            }
        }

        private static string ReadInput(string fileName)
        {
            string output;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                output  = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

I know my regular expression is incorrect but I don't know what to change.

The output:

```
Word ----> 2
S ----> 2
MissingWord ----> 0
DS ----> 2
aa ----> 0
```

The correct output:

```
Word --> 9
S --> 13
MissingWord --> 0
DS --> 2
aa --> 3
```

file.txt contains:

```
Word? We have few words: first word, second word, third word.
Some passwords: PASSWORD123, @PaSsWoRd!456, AAaA, !PASSWORD
```

words.txt contains:

```
Word
S
MissingWord
DS
aa
```

Comment: "I know my regular expression is incorrect" We never know if that claim is true until you posted your code. I am 99% sure its wrong

Comment: Please post your `file.txt` contents

Comment: Strings in .NET are immutable. So need to write `input = input.ToLower();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post the file.txt contents first, otherwise it's difficult to verify if the regex is working correctly or not.

That being said, check out the Regex answer here:
[Finding ALL positions of a substring in a large string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp)
and see if that helps with your code in the mean time.

edit:

So there's a simple solution, add "(?=(" and "))" to each of your phrases. This is a lookahead assertion in regex. The following code handles what you want.

```
        foreach (string phrase in phrases) {
            string MatchPhrase = "(?=(" + phrase.ToLower() + "))";
            int mathes = Regex.Matches(input, MatchPhrase).Count;
            Console.WriteLine(phrase + " ----> " + mathes);
        }
```

You also had an issue with

```
input.ToLower();
```

which should be instead

```
input = input.ToLower();
```

as strings in c# are immutable. In total, your code should be:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string input = ReadInput("file.txt");
        input = input.ToLower();
        List<string> phrases = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("words.txt")) {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null) {
                phrases.Add(line.Trim());
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        foreach (string phrase in phrases) {
            string MatchPhrase = "(?=(" + phrase.ToLower() + "))";
            int mathes = Regex.Matches(input, MatchPhrase).Count;
            Console.WriteLine(phrase + " ----> " + mathes);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(50000);
    }

    private static string ReadInput(string fileName) {
        string output;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
            output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: I posted the contents of file.txt

Comment: Are you looking to only match explicitly, such that 'aa' doesn't match 'aaa' or 'aaAaa', only matching 'aa'?

Comment: in AAaA, aa will match 3 times

Comment: First thing you'll need to do then is convert the input line to lowercase. Regex won't match 'aa' to 'AA'. You could also insert a (?i) to the front of every regex pattern to make it case insensitive.

Next regex is just looking for a single match the way you've got it setup. It will match 'aa' to 'aaaa' once and move on. Look at the link I posted in the answer for an answer to find every occurrence of the substring

Comment: Look closer I'm converting it to lowercase.

Comment: My bad, I missed that. Updating answer with a closer Regex answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer-  try that? It's not pretty and I'm sure there's a better way to iterate over the string but this should return 3 for a regex "aa" and source "aaaa"

Comment: can you please update your code so that will be inserted easily in my old code

Comment: Just replace your line "int mathes = regex.Matches(input).Count;" with my code.

Comment: Yes. I've used the same variable names from your code, so you just copy and paste it. It should fit directly in. I've edited my answer to show a little more easily how to fit that in your code.

Comment: cannot assign  phrase because it's a foreach iteration. I tried with for loop still is not working

Comment: Updated. Try that?

Comment: Use regex.ToString(). And still isn't working, all the values are 0. I don't know why maybe try it on your own PC?

Comment: @Dan Try this. I tested it with your input and phrases and it gives the right output.

Comment: What is it giving you? I tried with your given inputs and it returned your given outputs.

Comment: The output is not correct:   Word ----> 5
S ----> 7
MissingWord ----> 0
DS ----> 2
aa ----> 0

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. It's got nothing to do with regex. You have a line "input.ToLower()" but it needs to be "input = input.ToLower();" instead. That will fix your problems. In c#, strings are immutable so calling just "input.ToLower()" doesn't do anything - it returns a string value you have to set another variable to.

Comment: That partially does the trick. My regex that I used is the words itself. Everything is correct but, at AAaA, aa matches only 2 times insted of three.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I posted my exact source code which is returning the correct values for your inputs, using the input files you gave. You need to use the MatchPhrase I gave you for your regex or it won't properly handle the AAaA case.

Comment: Oh Yes. Thanks a lot. You really helped me and guided me all the way. Also thanks for your time:)

Comment: No problem! I had to learn about the lookahead for regex too, was a learning experience for the both of us

Answer (score 2):

here is what happened. I am going to use Word as example.

the regex you built for "word" is ".*word.*". It is telling regex to match anything starts with anything, contains "word" and ends with anything.

for your input, it matched

Word? We have few words: first **word**, second word, third word.

which starts with `"Word? We have few words: first"` and ends with `", second word, third word."`

then second line starts with `"Some pass"` contains `"word"` and ends with `": PASSWORD123, @PaSsWoRd!456, AAaA, !PASSWORD"`

so the count is 2

the regex you want is simple, string `"word"` is sufficient.

Update:

for ignore case pattern try `"(?i)word"`

And for the multiple matches within AAaA, try `"(?i)(?<=a)a"`

`?<=` is a Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion

Comment: @Dan try "(?i)word"

Comment: It worked for all cases except aa. It matched 2 times instead of three.

Comment: I need to use same regex for all words, so please format the regex like that : Regex regex = new Regex(String.Format(".*" + phrase.ToLower() + ".*")); But with correct expression.

Comment: @Dan string.Format("(?i)(?<={0})", phrase)

Comment: all the values are 0. Maybe it doesn't recognize them. Maybe try the code on your own machine?

Comment: @Dan put this whole line in. Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("(?i)(?<={0})", phrase));
There is no way it doesn't recognize them on mine but not yours

Comment: There are two identical errors in code: unexpected character ". What does it mean?

Comment: @Dan IDK what you have done there. But those two lines

Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("(?i)(?<={0})", "aa"));

Console.WriteLine(regex.Matches("AAaA").Count); //3

worked for me

Comment: @Dan if those two lines work on your machine then it means your problem lies somewhere else. Its time to do some debugging.

Comment: it does not compile. The error: 
Unexpected character '‌'

Comment: @Dan Type it in. Don't copy paste. SO inserted some special invisible characters before the quote

Comment: Now I don't know which of answers to mark as "answer"

Comment: @Dan whichever answer you feel like best answered your question is the answer. No pressure there

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");

foreach (string word in File.ReadLines("words.txt"))
{
    var regex = new Regex(word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    int startat = 0;
    int count = 0;

    Match match = regex.Match(input, startat);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        count++;
        startat = match.Index + 1;
        match = regex.Match(input, startat);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(word + "\t" + count);
}
```

To correctly find all substrings like "aa", had to use the overload `Match` method with `startat` parameter.

Note the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` parameter.

A shorter but less clear code:

```
Match match;
while ((match = regex.Match(input, startat)).Success)
{
    count++;
    startat = match.Index + 1;
}
```

Comment: No need for ignore case because I use\ toLower method

Comment: @Dan - But I don't. ;)