# Finding multiple semi predictable patterns in a string

Tags: c#, arrays, find

Alright, so I'm writing an application that needs to be able to extract a VAT-Number from an invoice (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAT_identification_number)

The biggest challenge to overcome here is that as apparent from the wikipedia article I have linked to, each country uses its own format for these VAT-numbers (The Netherlands uses a 14 character number while Germany uses a 11 character number).

In order to extract these numbers, I throw every line from the invoice into an array of strings, and for each string I test if it has a length that is equal to one of the VAT formats, and if that checks out, I check if said string also contains a country code ("NL", "DE", etc).

```
 string[] ProcessedFile = Reader.ProcessFile(Input);
            foreach(string S in ProcessedFile)
            {
                RtBEditor.AppendText(S + "\n");
            }

            foreach(string X in ProcessedFile)
            {
                string S = X.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                if (S.Length == 7)
                {
                    if (S.Contains("GBGD"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Land = Groot Britanie (Regering)");
                    }
            }
            /*
repeat for all other lenghts and country codes.
*/
```

The problem with this code is that 1st:
if there is a string that happens to have the same length as one of the VAT-formats, and it has a country code embedded in it, the code will incorrectly think that it has found the VAT-number.
2nd:
In some cases, the VAT-number will be included like "VAT-number: [VAT-number]". In this case, the text that precedes the actual number will be added to its length, making the program unable to detect the actual VAT-Number.

The best way to fix this is in my assumption to somehow isolate the VAT-Number from the strings all together, but I have yet to find a way how to actually do this.

Does anyone by any chance know any potential solution?

Many thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: 
Added a dummy invoice to clarify what kind of data is contained within the invoices.
[image]

Comment: I would like to suggest you to have a list of regex patterns with all the expected formats (for eg. one for DE, one for NL) in a list and validate it with each line you are reading from the file. Hope this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958324/search-for-some-phrases-in-a-text-file-using-regex-c-sharp) will help you to achieve this.

Comment: Does the file contain a Country code?  Rather than try to get VAT just from the string it is much easier to first know the country and then parse the VAT based on country.

Comment: If you provide some good amount of input data someone may figure out for you a better solution if your doesn't work.

Comment: *I throw every line from the invoice into an array of strings*? What is this invoice made of? Doesn't it have all the informations needed to determine those parameters? The country code, for example? Why are you *throwing everything* to strings? Can you post a sample of these invoices? You just need a common mapper, as a Dictionary, to match the country code and its VAT or the VAT format.

Comment: @Sivaprasath I'll look into this and will get back to you when I found something.

Comment: @jdweng This depends on the invoice (I get multiple invoices from multiple sources), some have a full country, some a country code and some just a city.

Comment: @Jimi These are invoices that contain order data (i.e.: 3 brown sweaters for €10,-.) since the invoices come from different sources, some contain more/different information than others. I'm afraid I can't post a direct sample invoice since they are considered 'sensitive information'. I can make a dummy invoice though, which I will add to this question. The reason I throw everything into string is because the invoices are extracting using OCR, so the output will be in strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone in the comments had pointed out, the best way to fix this is by using Regex. After trying around a bit I came to the following solution:

```
        public Regex FilterNormaal = new Regex(@"[A-Z]{2}(\d)+B?\d*");
        private void BtnUitlezen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RtBEditor.Clear();
            /*
             Temp dummy vatcodes for initial testing.
             */
            Form1.Dummy1.VAT = "NL855291886B01";
            Form1.Dummy2.VAT = "DE483270846";
            Form1.Dummy3.VAT = "SE482167803501";
            OCR Reader = new OCR();
            /*
             Grab and process image
             */
            if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    Input = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please open an image file.");
                }
            }
            string[] ProcessedFile = Reader.ProcessFile(Input);
            foreach(string S in ProcessedFile)
            {
                string X = S.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                RtBEditor.AppendText(X + "\n");
            }


            foreach (Match M in FilterNormaal.Matches(RtBEditor.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(M.Value);
            }    
}
```

At first, I attempted to iterate through my array of strings to find a match, but for reasons unknown, this did not yield any results. When applying the regex to the entire textbox, it did output the results I needed.