# Is it possible to change only the lambda operator color in VS2015 Professional?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, editor

I want to have more control over the colors in my code editor. For example, I wanted to change the color of the lambda operator, =>,  to be different from the other ones. I would also like if it was possible to change the color of extension methods only while leaving other methods with default color (or vice versa), and changing the colors of the lambda keywords when they appear in a lambda context.

Is any of this possible with some neat VS extension (or maybe even with the default editor customization options)?

**EDIT:** I created this class and copy pasted the method from the answer:

```
static class StringExtensionMethods
{
    public static List<int> AllIndexesOf ( this string str, string value )
    {
        if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty ( value ) )
            throw new ArgumentException ( "the string to find may not be empty", "value" );
        List<int> indexes = new List<int> ( );
        for ( int index = 0; ; index += value.Length )
        {
            index = str.IndexOf ( value, index );
            if ( index == -1 )
                return indexes;
            indexes.Add ( index );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you create a public github project with the extension and test projects we could help collaborate on a solution.  I am hoping to write a similar extension.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy to write such an extension yourself.

First, create an Extensibility - Visual Studio Extension project.
Then, add a `Editor Classifier item`.
That will place a number of files into the project, you need the one called `EditorClassfier1.cs` (or similar).

In it, you will find the `GetClassificationSpans` method.
How this system works is that VS will use MEF and execute this method constantly as something changes in the editor. So you just need to return a list of `ClassificationSpan` objects providing a relevant `ClassificationType` and the start and end positions.

A quick thing i put together like so:

```
public IList<ClassificationSpan> GetClassificationSpans(SnapshotSpan span)
    {
      var result = new List<ClassificationSpan>();
      foreach (var line in span.Snapshot.Lines.Where(x => x.GetText().Contains("=>")))
      {

        foreach (var idx in line.GetText().AllIndexesOf("=>"))
        {
         result.Add(new ClassificationSpan(new SnapshotSpan(line.Snapshot, new Span(line.Start.Position + idx, 2)), this.classificationType));
        }
      };

      return result;
    }
```

Results in this (note: the background highlighting is what `Editor Classifier` template generates as a sample, you can control this however you want).
[image: Screenshot]

For the implementation of `AllIndexesOf` check out this answer:
[Finding ALL positions of a substring in a large string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp)

P.S. One thing that is a good idea to change from the defaults is on the `IClassifierProvider` class you would get `[ContentType("text")]` by default. Might be a good idea to change that to `[ContentType("code")]` as this syntax highlighting only makes sense for code.

Comment: thanks, I will try to make this extension. My latest attempt at making one was very frustrating, but my pretensions were far more ambitious.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman If it wasn't for 2015 i can kind of see why, some of the things were quite more difficult. With 2015 they made extensibility even easier for certain scenarios, such as this one.

Comment: I must have done something wrong because it is highlighting all lines completely, from column 0 to the end of the line, every single line with any code is being highlighted. I changed `ContentType` to `"code"`, as you told me, and got the same result. I copy-pasted the thing that worked for you, how can it not work for me?

Comment: The one from the link you posted

Comment: @FinnTheHuman Short of posting all the code somewhere i am not sure what we can try :)