# Function / Regular Expression to match string parts within a larger string & highlight the parts

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to build a function that takes a search string and matches the parts within a larger string & highlights them. See example below:

**Original String:** Since there is limited overhead space on the plane, I assure you, there will be no fee for checking the bags, I can go ahead and fill out all the checked baggage forms for you.

**Text to Search & Highlight:** no fee, I fill out the forms

**Desired Result:** Since there is limited overhead space on the plane, I assure you, there will be ***no fee*** for checking the bags***, I*** can go ahead and ***fill out*** all ***the*** checked baggage ***forms*** for you.

I can search for the complete string or search one word at a time using substring, but neither of which produces the desired result. The trick may be to somehow recursively search starting with the full string, and gradually breaking it up into smaller pieces, until the parts are matched. There are a couple assumptions:

- The search must be as greedy as possible i.e. match largers parts of the string before trying to match smaller parts or individual words.
- The search will always progress forward after any match that is found i.e. if the first 2 words are found at location x, then words 3 and 4 will always be after x, not before x.

Hope that makes sense. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have searched the site, but haven't found anything similar to what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: If you now include one attempt that you tried to make a regular expression then it will be the perfect regex question and I will always use it as reference to point users to "how to post the perfect regex question"

Comment: great resource for creating regular expressions: https://regex101.com

Comment: Does it mean you have `var lst = new List<string>() {"no fee", "I fill out the forms"};`?

Comment: No, the search string I have is `var lst = new List<string>() {"no fee, I fill out the forms"}` and that needs to be searched starting with the full string but recursively in parts as needed.

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/WFJmTp). Some redundant tags are added though, but overall result might be what you need.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work in my initial tests, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps you. It is not using Regex to find the strings, simply `IndexOf`.

It first gets the words to highlight as `Tuple` which represent start index and end index of the word.

The it highlights the text using a prefix and suffix that will surround the word (here: html tags).

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = "Since there is limited overhead space on the plane, I assure you, there will be no fee for checking the bags, I can go ahead and fill out all the checked baggage forms for you";
    var searchExpression = "no fee, I fill out the forms";

    var highlightedInput = HighlightString(input, searchExpression, "<b>", "</b>");

    Console.WriteLine(highlightedInput);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetHighlights(string input, string searchExpression)
{
    var splitIntoWordsRegex = new Regex(@"\W+");
    var words = splitIntoWordsRegex.Split(searchExpression);
    return GetHighlights(input, words);
}

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetHighlights(string input, IEnumerable<string> searchExpression)
{
    var highlights = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    var lastMatchedIndex = 0;
    foreach (var word in searchExpression)
    {
        var indexOfWord = input.IndexOf(word, lastMatchedIndex,  StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
        var lastIndexOfWord = indexOfWord + word.Length;

        highlights.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(indexOfWord, lastIndexOfWord));

        lastMatchedIndex = lastIndexOfWord;
    }

    return highlights;
}

public static string HighlightString(string input, string searchExpression, string highlightPrefix, string highlightSufix)
{
    var highlights = GetHighlights(input, searchExpression).ToList();

    var output = input;
    for (int i = 0, j = highlights.Count; i<j; i++)
    {
        int diffInputOutput = output.Length - input.Length;
        output = output.Insert(highlights[i].Item1 + diffInputOutput, highlightPrefix);

        diffInputOutput = output.Length - input.Length;
        output = output.Insert(highlights[i].Item2 + diffInputOutput, highlightSufix);
    }

    return output;
}
```

================== EDIT ======================

In order to reduce the min/max indexes highlighted, you can use the code below. While not being the prettiest, does the job.

It gets all the indexes available for a word (thanks to [Finding ALL positions of a substring in a large string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp)). Adds them to the `highlights`, then manipulates this collection to keep the closes matches from what you need.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetHighlights(string input, IEnumerable<string> searchExpression)
{
    var highlights = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();

    // Finds all the indexes for 
    // all the words found.
    foreach (var word in searchExpression)
    {
        var allIndexesOfWord = AllIndexesOf(input, word, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        highlights.AddRange(allIndexesOfWord.Select(index => new Tuple<string, int, int>(word, index, index + word.Length)));
    }

    // Reduce the scope of the highlights in order to 
    // keep the indexes as together as possible.
    var firstWord = searchExpression.First();
    var firstWordIndex = highlights.IndexOf(highlights.Last(x => String.Equals(x.Item1, firstWord)));

    var lastWord = searchExpression.Last();
    var lastWordIndex = highlights.IndexOf(highlights.Last(x => String.Equals(x.Item1, lastWord)));

    var sanitizedHighlights = highlights.SkipWhile((x, i) => i < firstWordIndex);
    sanitizedHighlights = sanitizedHighlights.TakeWhile((x, i) => i <= lastWordIndex);

    highlights = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();
    foreach (var word in searchExpression.Reverse())
    {
        var lastOccurence = sanitizedHighlights.Last((x) => String.Equals(x.Item1, word));
        sanitizedHighlights = sanitizedHighlights.TakeWhile(x => x.Item3 < lastOccurence.Item2);
        highlights.Add(lastOccurence);
    }

    highlights.Reverse();

    return highlights.Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.Item2, x.Item3));
}

public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(string str, string value, StringComparison comparison)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");

    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for (int index = 0; ; index += value.Length)
    {
        index = str.IndexOf(value, index, comparison);
        if (index == -1)
            return indexes;
        indexes.Add(index);
    }
}
```

Using this code and the text:

`"No, about the fee, since there is limited overhead space on the plane, I assure you, there will be no fee for checking the bags, I can go ahead and fill out all the checked baggage forms for you."`

I got the following result:

No, about the fee, since there is limited overhead space on the plane, I assure you, there will be **no** **fee** for checking the bags, **I** can go ahead and **fill** **out** all **the** checked baggage **forms** for you.

======================================================

**Edit 2** Using a Regex approach with the experience gained through the previous tries. 
Please note that if every word in the expression are not found, no highlights will be found.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> GetHighlights(string expression, string search)
{
    var highlights = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();

    var wordsToHighlight = new Regex(@"(\w+|[^\s]+)").
        Matches(search).
        Cast<Match>().
        Select(x => x.Value);

    foreach(var wordToHighlight in wordsToHighlight)
    {
        Regex findMatchRegex = null;
        if (new Regex(@"\W").IsMatch(wordToHighlight))
            findMatchRegex = new Regex(String.Format(@"({0})", wordToHighlight), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);  // is punctuation
        else
            findMatchRegex = new Regex(String.Format(@"((?<!\w){0}(?!\w))", wordToHighlight), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // si word

        var matches = findMatchRegex.Matches(expression).Cast<Match>().Select(match => new Tuple<string, int, int>(wordToHighlight, match.Index, match.Index + wordToHighlight.Length));

        if (matches.Any())
            highlights.AddRange(matches);
        else
            return new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    }

    // Reduce the scope of the highlights in order to 
    // keep the indexes as together as possible.
    var firstWord = wordsToHighlight.First();
    var firstWordIndex = highlights.IndexOf(highlights.Last(x => String.Equals(x.Item1, firstWord)));

    var lastWord = wordsToHighlight.Last();
    var lastWordIndex = highlights.IndexOf(highlights.Last(x => String.Equals(x.Item1, lastWord)));

    var sanitizedHighlights = highlights.SkipWhile((x, i) => i < firstWordIndex);
    sanitizedHighlights = sanitizedHighlights.TakeWhile((x, i) => i <= lastWordIndex);

    highlights = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();
    foreach (var word in wordsToHighlight.Reverse())
    {
        var lastOccurence = sanitizedHighlights.Last((x) => String.Equals(x.Item1, word));
        sanitizedHighlights = sanitizedHighlights.TakeWhile(x => x.Item3 < lastOccurence.Item2);
        highlights.Add(lastOccurence);
    }

    highlights.Reverse();

    return highlights.Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.Item2, x.Item3));
}
```

It is to be noted as well this approach now takes care of punctuation. the following results are found.

**Input:**
`No, about the fee, since there is limited overhead space on the plane, I assure you, there will be no fee for checking the bags, I can go ahead and fill out all the checked baggage forms for you.`
**Searching:**
`no fee, I fill out the forms`
**Output:**
No, about the fee, since there is limited overhead space on the plane, I assure you, there will be **no** **fee** for checking the bags**,** **I** can go ahead and **fill** **out** all **the** checked baggage **forms** for you.

**Input:**
`When First Class Glass receives your call, we will assign a repair person to visit you to assist.`
**Searching:**
`we assign a repair person`
**Output:**
When First Class Glass receives your call, **we** will **assign** **a** **repair** **person** to visit you to assist.

Comment: Thank you, I truly appreciate the help. Given that I did not have a working solution, this is much better. But it doesn't work in all cases, I'm trying to work through it.

Comment: Would you have a case that does not work? Maybe it is just a small tweat required (hoppefully)

Comment: One, it ignores punctuation, but I can live with that. More important, if you change the input string to `"No, about the fee, since there is limited overhead space on the plane, I assure you, there will be no fee for checking the bags, I can go ahead and fill out all the checked baggage forms for you."` it catches the first occurrence of no and fee (InvariantCultureIgnoreCase). It should find the consecutive "no fee" that occurs later in the string

Comment: Check out the edit and let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: So it works better in some cases, but gives an error for other cases.

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter accidentally. In this code: `foreach (var word in searchExpression.Reverse())
    {
        var lastOccurence = sanitizedHighlights.Last((x) => String.Equals(x.Item1, word));
        sanitizedHighlights = sanitizedHighlights.TakeWhile(x => x.Item3 < lastOccurence.Item2);
        highlights.Add(lastOccurence);
    }` the takewhile removes more words than those that get added to the highlights. Try this test case: `When First Class Glass receives your call, we will assign a repair person to visit you to assist.` and search `When we assign a repair person`

Comment: Please see the last update. Rolledback to a Regex based solution. It is using Regex in a tricky way but it appears to handle more cases.