# how to search words two or more words present in text file c#

Tags: c#

I have 3 text files namely

```
input.txt
array1.txt
array2.txt
```

input.txt file consist of lines like:

```
 the file in
 the computer is 
removedby user,
there are seven
 wonders in the      world 
ithink...
```

array1.txt file consist of:

```
computer 
user 
good
```

array2.txt file consist of:

```
seven
world 
none
```

I want to check the presence of words in input.txt with the array1.txt and array2.txt

what I am trying to say is eg: the word in input.txt is match with the word in array1.txt means output must be "computer" is present in array1. if the word match with array2.txt means it should show the word present in array2.

output: words computer and user is present in array1 words world and seven is present in array2

my code in c#:

```
int count;
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:/Users/input.txt"))
{
  string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
  MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(contents, "computer", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  count = matches.Count;
 }
if (count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("present");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("absent");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code effort

Comment: glad to have a response, i am new to c# now just completed the code to show the text in text file to the grid view and i have no idea about comparing the text file need help

Comment: Please refer to SO How To Ask. Questions on SO must show the effort you did. We cannot write your code for you but help correct it. Break it up to smaller tasks. How to read all lines from file, how to check if a string is contained in another. For/foreach loops.

Comment: You need to know about reading file contents in string and string comparison. Try to use those in your solution. Come back if you face any issues while using that approach. Logic wise you need to get the conents of input.txt in string, get contents of array1.txt and array2.txt in string array and check if their items existing in input.txt content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a different approach:

1. For reading the file (unless it is a very big file where streaming is needed) I'd use `File.ReadAllText` or `File.ReadAllLines`.
2. For checking the presence of a string from your array in the text I'd go for `Contains` instead of regex.
3. And finally I'd use linq [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) method to check a predicate for each item in the array

So:

```
var arr1 = File.ReadAllLines("array1.txt"); // Reading to get string[] - item for each line
var arr2 = File.ReadAllLines("array2.txt");
var input = File.ReadAllText("input.txt"); // Reading to get one string for all text

var arr1WordsInInput = arr1.Where(input.Contains);
var arr2WordsInInput = arr2.Where(input.Contains);
```

---

If you want to find all indexes of matches you can use function proposed in answer for this question [Finding ALL positions of a substring in a large string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641326/6400526) like this:

```
var result = arr1.Select(w => new {  Word = w, Indexes = input.AllIndexesOf(w) })
                 .Where(w => w.Indexes.Any());
```

This will return an `IEnumerable` where each item contains two properties: the matching word and the indexes where it was found within the `input` text