# How can I find a certain letter in a String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, loops, char, letter

How can I search a certain letter (char) in a String?

I have to code a little riddle. You basicalley have to guess the right letters of an unknown word. Only the first letter is shown.

Example: "Apple"

A____ --> that's what you actually see. Now, the player has to input a letter/char and if it is inculded in the String "Apple", the correct letter will be added.

Example: input = e
A___e

Thx.

Comment: Your choice of tags would seem to indicate you already know one answer: **loop** thru the **chars** in the **string** to see if it matches the **letter** entered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all positions of substring in a larger string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-substring-in-a-larger-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it so many times on my own using loops but I just was not able to get the correct result. That's why I am here.

Comment: Next time, if you post the code you have tried and are working with, you are much less likely to collect downvotes.  As posted this is asking 'how to write a program' which is too broad.  Visit the [help] and study some of the topic there like [ask]

Comment: Well, for me votes are not that important. I am satisfied with the most simple answers. Like "You can use IndexOf" or soemthing like that. If people are kind enough to show me the actual code, that is a bonus for me. My code was not even something you could really work with. The whole char-searching part was missing because I did not know what to add and the rest was just a loop. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof).

Example:

```
var str = "Apple";
var c = 'p';
var i = str.IndexOf(c);
// i will be the index of the first occurrence of 'p' in str, or -1 if not found.

if (i == -1)
{
    // not found
}
else
{
    do
    {
        // do something with index i, which is != -1
        i = str.IndexOf(c, i + 1);
    } while (i != -1);
}
```

Comment: What about the character 'p' in "Apple"?

Comment: You will get the first index (1), then as it's not -1, you can start on i + 1: `str.IndexOf('p', i + 1)`, and you can repeat this until you get -1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all letter indices, you can try this LINQ solution:

```
var str = "Apple";
var letter = 'p';

var charIndexMap = str
    .Select((ch, idx) => (ch, idx))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.ch)
    .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, 
                  entry => entry.Select(pair => pair.idx));

if (charIndexMap.TryGetValue(letter, out var value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(", ", value) + "]");
} else
{
    // not found
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2]
```

**Explanation:**

- Use [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) to map over the characters and indices and convert them to `(character, index)` tuples.
- Use [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) to group tuples by character.
- Convert grouped results to a dictionary using [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8), which maps each character to an `IEnumerable<int>` of indices.
- Use [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, TValue)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8) to get the associated indices for the letter.